# Pygame updating variable in a function

Tags: python, pygame

The problem is that when I made it without the run of functions it worked fine, however it seems to now always reset back to 0. I have missed off other bits of code, but it will load the first function then when it comes out of the second function it resets back to 0.

```
   if letter == "G":
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_g and x > 192 and x <250:
            score += 1
            texts(score,gameDisplay)
def texts(score,gameDisplay):
   font=pygame.font.Font(None,100)
   scoretext=font.render(str(score), 1,(204,0,204))
   gameDisplay.blit(scoretext, (313, 617))
   return score
```

Answer (score 0):

do a score=0 before the for loop.

```
if letter == "G":
    score=0
    for event in...
```

EDIT: 
you should initialize the score somewhere outside of the game loop

Comment: but this would set score to 0 before when the text is displayed so that it would still only show 0

Comment: yes this is wrong, he needs to keep track of the score somewhere outside of the whole game loop.